# CSS Absolute Problem

Tags: css, position, html-lists, absolute

Can anyone offer suggestions as to how I can get the "new" icon to display correctly as absolute over the forum category images? [my website](http://www.gameralien.com/forum/)

I want it to display over each category image, yet it only does the first one.

Comment: A screenshot of the misplaced image and the related code would be beneficial :) I'm not seeing it on my end (Chrome 12)

Comment: Sorry just updated it. Check again please. thanks.

Comment: I don't even see the problem (FF 4.0.1). The icon seems to be already on the right position.

Comment: @Jackson Over each category image.. just like it shows in the first image. The icon "new" must be on every category image where there are new threads posted.

Comment: @Jonas - I want it over every category image, not just the first one.

Comment: @Brandon: It is over every category image.

Comment: i think he is talking about the (new) image only being on the first image. and wants it on each category... see my answer @brandon

Comment: @Matthias @Jonas weird, I see it on mine

Answer (score 2):

use the css :

```
ul.listf li {
   ...
   position: relative;
}
```

and for the new image:

```
ul.listf li .newf{
   ...
   position:absolute;
   top:12px;
   left: 143px;
}
```

the important part is setting your list item position to relative so the absolute position will depend on the position of the list

Comment: THANK YOU lbu! that did it. you rock.

I was so close.

I had .listf { position:relative; } no wonder it only displayed there.. thank you